# Redmine installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04, redmine

While Following the steps in redmine installation

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall

```
me@me:/redmine-2.3$ sudo rake generate_secret_token
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Gem::SourceIndex
/redmine-2.3/config/boot.rb:6
/redmine-2.3/config/application.rb:1
/redmine-2.3/Rakefile:5
```

in Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
How to resolve this ?

Comment: did you run `bundle install` ?

Comment: yes till step 4 all went fine

Comment: can you please show me your rvm/ruby version and rails version

Comment: me@me:/redmine-2.3$ bundle show rack
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.5

Comment: `bundle exec rake generate_secret_token` please try this

Comment: me@me:/redmine-2.3$  ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]

Comment: ok....`bundle exec rake generate_secret_token` is it running? and also `gem -v`

Comment: it works :)sree@sree:/redmine-2.3$ sudo  RAILS_ENV=production db:migrate
sudo: db:migrate: command not found

Comment: ok...can you please vote me up I f I make it in a post

Comment: thanks.........you can try `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: Hi @guny it is not opening

Comment: what is your gamil id

Comment: not exposed to public

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your gem 
`gem -v` >= 1.7
If you ran `bundle install` and it is successfully completed
Then can you
ok....`bundle exec rake generate_secret_token`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What version of bundler are you running? Try `gem install bundler` and verify that it's a version 1.3.x or higher. I've seen references that the error occurs due to older versions of bundler.

Not directly related to RedMine but a similar issue: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/536

Comment: sree@sree:/redmine-2.3$ sudo gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.3.5

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed redmine in ubuntu via docker (https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-redmine). All redmine dependencies are located in a isolated container without populating the operating system (only docker is needed -> https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/).

> Docker containers wrap up a piece of software in a complete filesystem
>   that contains everything it needs to run: code, runtime, system tools,
>   system libraries – anything you can install on a server. This
>   guarantees that it will always run the same, regardless of the
>   environment it is running in.

```
sudo apt-get install docker-engine
sudo service docker start
docker run --name=redmine -it --rm -p 10080:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/bin/docker sameersbn/redmine:latest
```